How do i get a Value from an Excel VBA cell?
This cant be that complicated, now can it? After reading for an hour, I still didnt find a working solution. I have a range _usage in a worksheet defs. I want to iterate thru the range's rows and output every first cell in the row.
Dim row As Range
Dim c As Range
For Each row In Worksheets("defs").Range("_usage").Rows
    c = row.Offset(0, 0)
    MsgBox "[" + CStr(c) + "]", , "Check"
Next row

Sadly in my different approaches I just get some weird errors (mismatching types without telling me what types it got and expected, undefined width-block-variable etc.)
How do I do this?

c = row.Offset(0, 0) ---> Set c = row.Cells(1). MsgBox "[" + CStr(c) + "]", , "Check": change the + to &, which forces string concatenation, and drop the CStr. Also it's more explicit to use c.Value.

Try this code:
Sub Test()
    Dim row As Range
    Dim c
    For Each row In Worksheets("defs").Range("_usage").Rows
        c = row(1).Value
        MsgBox "[" & c(1, 1) & "]", , "Check"
    Next row
End Sub

or
Sub Test2()
    Dim row As Range
    For Each row In Worksheets("defs").Range("_usage").Rows
        MsgBox "[" & row.Cells(1).Value & "]", , "Check"
    Next row
End Sub

The second version is also good for single column case.

Difference between Value, Value2 and Text
